# Does SVD work for non-square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I'm trying to decompose a matrix of keypoints for Tomasi-Kanada factorization

I am not doing this by hand right now simply because there are libraries available for this and I know I will get the wrong answer

I am using Real Statistics Resource Pack for Excel

The Matrix I am decomposing is $W$

When I run `SVD_U()` on the entire matrix I get `# Value`

But when I run `SVD_U()` on just the first 6 keypoints, I get a correct $U$ matrix out,

I tested the SVD of this matrix and they do multiply out correctly to original matrix, but this way I cannot use more than 6 keypoints

Is this a problem with this toolkit, or is there a problem with decomposing a rectangular matrix like this?

Am I just doing something wrong?

Or is there a better toolkit for Excel that I can use?
I have Matlab as well if that works better

[image]

Comment: The SVD is defined for matrices of any size. MATLAB would be immensely better-suited for this task.

Comment: @MiPo [This demo](https://real-statistics.com/linear-algebra-matrix-topics/singular-value-decomposition/) show how the SVD computation works using that package in excel. The matrix of interest here has shape $3 \times 4$.